# Format fractional percent in java yields very strange behaviour

Tags: java, number-formatting

I am trying to format percentages with the following code:

```
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
fmt.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
fmt.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
System.out.println(fmt.format(0.145));
```

However, I get a very strange result:

> 14%

Changing the value 0.145 to something else, for example 0.125 will work properly and the result will be as expected

> 13%

Can someone shed some light on this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the inherent rounding error in `double`, resulting in `0.145` being rounded to

```
0.1449999999999999900079927783735911361873149871826171875
```

Use `BigDecimal` if you expect perfect accuracy.

Comment: Out of curiosity, Why is not same for 0.125?

Comment: Because 0.125 can be exactly represented as a fraction in binary, since it's equal to `1/8`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is an result of the intern representation of floats. (Decimal numbers represented by binary numbers).

Your 0.145 might be internally represented as 0.144999999999..., so rounding mode rounds down.

Answer (score 1):

You should read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://www.google.com/url?url=http://web.cse.msu.edu/~cse320/Documents/FloatingPoint.pdf&rct=j&sa=U&ei=u0M5T_j6LoSniQKc6aWPCg&ved=0CC0QFjAB&sig2=WWCgt0EDZJ_emukK1k5nkw&q=What%20every%20computer%20scientist%20should%20know%20about%20floating%20point&usg=AFQjCNGYpDfrAMwOFy1UXiIaFeASHEQNUw&cad=rja), but basically it comes down to the fact that .145 can't be exactly represented in IEEE floating point, and so gets rounded to the nearest value that can be represented, which just happens to be slightly less that .145, so it gets rounded down when rounded to two digits.